# ASP.NET 4.5 MVC4 Model Binding Issue - Cannot define any models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.5

I'm having trouble with MVC4 not being able to bind to anything.

For Example:

```
    public class Question
    {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Int32 QuestionID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Int32 SurveyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Int32 QuestionNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]  
    public Boolean AssignedToAPage { get; set; }
    }
```

I create a strongly typed view using Add View and select the above class:

```
    @model Models.Question

    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "View1";
       Layout = "~/Views/Layouts/_Site.Layout.cshtml";
    }

<h2>View1</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Question</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SurveyID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SurveyID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SurveyID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuestionNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionNumber)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssignedToAPage)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssignedToAPage)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssignedToAPage)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

So, after generating this page, I try going to it and I get the following error:
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'SurveyID' and no extension method 'SurveyID' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is this just an issue with Visual Studio 2012 RC?  Do I need to reinstall something?  I've googled this issue a view times but I've yet to find anything relevant.  I've resorted to explicitly casting Model to the type but that seems to defeat the purpose of having @model.  Any input would be useful! Thanks.

Update

```
Apparently I caused the issue by following someone else's advice on creating a custom view page class.  I created the following: 

public abstract class CustomWebViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public ContentVersionHelper ContentVersion { get; set; }
    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        ContentVersion = new ContentVersionHelper(base.ViewContext, this);
    }
}

public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage
    where TModel : class
{
    public ContentVersionHelper<TModel> ContentVersion { get; set; }
    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        ContentVersion = new ContentVersionHelper<TModel>(base.ViewContext, this);
    }
}
```

Didn't even taken into consideration that I needed to derive from WebViewPage on the 2nd class.  After adding that, everything was fixed.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Can you show your controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom classes should be updated to match the following:

```
public abstract class CustomWebViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public ContentVersionHelper ContentVersion { get; set; }
    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        ContentVersion = new ContentVersionHelper(base.ViewContext, this);
    }
}

public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
    where TModel : class
{
    public ContentVersionHelper<TModel> ContentVersion { get; set; }
    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        ContentVersion = new ContentVersionHelper<TModel>(base.ViewContext, this);
    }
}
```